# Eloquent ORM Transactions when inserting to multiples tables?

Tags: php, laravel

When inserting to 3 tables using Eloquent ORM in Laravel, is there some way to make sure that if one insertion fails then they all fail? Since it's a many-to-many relation, I need to be sure all 3 inserts, well...inserted.

Here's a sample table structure:

```
tbl_users
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
name VARCHAR(100)

tbl_cars
id INT AUTO_INCREMENT
brand VARCHAR(100)

tbl_user_cars
user_id INT
car_id INT
count TINYINT
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://forums.laravel.io/viewtopic.php?id=1464 and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105640/laravel-eloquent-orm-transactions) too. I tested this piece of code on laravel-3 and i think it should be pretty similar in laravel 4. Here's my code :

```
try {
    DB::connection()->pdo->beginTransaction();
    //Do some operation here
    DB::connection()->pdo->commit();
} 
catch (\PDOException $e) {
    //Rollback if fails
    DB::connection()->pdo->rollBack();
}
```