# Laravel 4, Turn DB::select into Eloquent object

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I tried this:

```
$result = (array)DB::selectOne('SELECT * FROM campaign WHERE id = ? FOR UPDATE', [$data['campaign_id']]);
$campaign = new Campaign($result);
$campaign->counter += 1;
$campaign->save();
```

But I get this error on save `Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '1' for key`, because it thinks I'm trying to work with a new campaign, not an existing one.

Edit: Why doesn't it know it exists, considering I have the primary key set.

Comment: why aren't you using Eloquent or fluent instead?

Comment: I think what I'm doing is too advanced for eloquent. I need to lock table rows. You can see I'm using `FOR UPDATE` in my query. I couldn't figure out how to do that, or anything custom with eloquent.

Comment: Would defining a transaction explicitly (as [show here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15105640/laravel-eloquent-orm-transactions)) be of help?

Comment: Yeah, my code is already inside a transaction

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it would be to set the `$exists` property to true before saving the object.

```
$campaign->exists = true;
$campaign->save();
```

This way it will trigger the `performUpdate()` method instead of `performInsert()`.

Comment: I think it's weird that I have to manually say it exists, but I guess the exists property is public for a reason. Looks good, I'll mark correct if it works.

Answer (score 0):

How about this instead...

$campaign = Campaign::find((int) $data['campaign_id']);

$campaign->counter += 1;

$campaign->save();

Comment: I can't use `FOR UPDATE` to lock records this way.

Comment: Just for the records, now you can do pessimistic locking using sharedLock and lockForUpdate (http://laravel.com/docs/queries#pessimistic-locking)